# Inserting CUE OUT and CUE IN advertisment markers in azure media Service?

Tags: azure, ads, azure-media-services

Hey guys i am using Azure Media services for live streaming purpose,and WireCast for live encoding the streaming, it works fine but now i need to insert ad marker such as #EXT-X-CUE-OUT:DURATION=30 indicating start of ad and #EXT-X-CUE-IN  indicating end of ad in mainfest meta data file for HLS Stream.
what should i do to achieve this implementation?

Comment: Made any progress on this?